# FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index.
> Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider
> adding ".indexOn": "status" at /groups/test/leadPropertyInformations
> to your security rules for better performance.

***Firebase RTD Rules***

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "groups": {
      ".indexOn": ["leadPropertyInformations/status"]
    }
  }
}
```

***JSON Tree***

**Note:** You cannot see `status` property. But it is there on the 3rd arrow path.

[image]

Query using `AngularFire`

```
getActiveLeadPropertyInformations(): Observable<LeadPropertyInformationModel[]> {
    return this.angularFireDatabase
      .list<LeadPropertyInformationModel>(
        `groups/${this.groupId}/leadPropertyInformations`,
        (ref) => ref.orderByChild('status').equalTo('active')
      )
      .valueChanges()

      .pipe(first());
  }
```

Can you tell me what was the issue with my Rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need more placeholders in your rule to make i work:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "groups": {
          "$groupId": {
             "leadPropertyInformations":{
               
          ".indexOn": ["status"]
         
        }
       }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is also not working? Any clue why? The same error above.

Comment: Try it with the updated version. That one is exactly on the path from the error message. You should also consider that the indexing doesn't happen immidiately. I would wait a little bit depeding on how many elements you have on that paths.

Comment: Sure, I'll try that and will let you know. I do have only 2 nodes since this is dev mode yet.

Comment: This is working fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The path is not correct (at least not as it's described in the question)

Your index is

```
leadPropertyInformations/status
```

and the path is actually

```
leadPropertyInformations/22611/status
```

Note the 22611 in the path - that means you'll need to add something to represent the child nodes like $an_id to reference the child nodes shown in the question.

Comment: This is not a solution at all since I need a generic solution here hence I don't know about the ids of the collection upfront.

Comment: @Sampath You're question asks **Can you tell me what was the issue with my Rule?** e.g. You wanted to know what the issue with your rule was, and this solution is the answer as it explains the issue. If you wanted to know how to write a generic rule, the question should have asked that - if you look a the screen shot the path is not generic, it's specific.